# Foreign key constraint check using JPA/Hibernate on a MySQL cluster

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have just been informed that `MySQL` clusters (using NDB engine) do not support foreign key constraints across clusters.

Using `JPA`/`Hibernate`, how would you enforce referential integrity if the database doesn't enforce it?

One option is to make a call to the database to validate the data then if valid perform the `insert/update/delete` operation. I am a bit reluctant to go with this approach as there is a performance impact.

Questions:

- How do you usually enforce referential integrity checks when using `MySQL` cluster with `JPA`/`Hibernate` if foreign key checks are not supported in the database.
- If a manual check is the only option, is there any way I can complete the manual check transaction with a single trip to the database? (Possibly as part of the `CRUD` operation)

Comment: I think you might have to define your own sanity/integrity checks in triggers...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to enforce the referential integrity using any Hibernate/JPA functionality.  As eggyal mentioned, you'll need to use triggers to create "programatic" foreign keys in MySQL itself.

There's an article on the MySQL website on how to do it: http://dev.mysql.com/tech-resources/articles/mysql-enforcing-foreign-keys.html